# Loop into a Tkinter instance

Tags: python, tkinter

I got a school project, in which I need to have a loop during all the time the Tkinter window is open.

I tried to use the `after_idle()` and `after` methods, but none of these worked.

I have the same problem on short test code:

```
from Tkinter import *

i = 0

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
l = Label(root, width = 200, height = 150)
l.pack(side = 'top')
b = Button(root, width = 10, height = 10)
b.pack()

def a():
    global i    
    i+=1
    l.configure(text = i)

root.after(10, a())

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

`root.after(10, a())` is very close to what you want, but the second argument `a()` runs `a` immediately and uses its return value (which is `None`).

You want to reference `a`, not run it. Use `root.after(10, a)`

---

Additionally, as pointed out by Bryan Oakley in the comments, you'll need some way to CONTINUE to schedule `a`. `root.after` only schedules the function to run once. The easiest way to do this is just to add `root.after(10, a)` to the function itself:

```
def a():
    global i
    root.after(10, a)  # re-schedule to run again
    i += 1
    l.configure(text=i)
```

Comment: That's half the solution. The other half is to make the same call from within `a` if you want it to loop continuously.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh i missed that requirement in the question. I'll edit my answer shortly